# Drop down dependent that pulls individual label ONLY - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to make a Dropdown dependent (Google Sheets) that categorizes data based on what you choose within the dropdown. What shows in the google searches are multiple dropdowns that changes depending on the selected dropdown, but what I'm looking for is one data that appears on the right side of the selected dropdown list already categorized.

Let's say the categories are as follows:
**Occupied:** Pending,In progress,For revision
**Vacant:** In review,On hold,Done,Cancelled

There will be 2 columns labeled as **status**, with a dropdown showing all the data from occupied and vacant in the left column, and on the right column, the occupied, or vacant shows up depending on what you have selected from the drop down.

This tracker is supposed to keep track my members and easily spot those who are vacant or currently occuppied depening on the status of their tasks.

I will attach below the link for the editable google sheet.

Please help me up on this, this will surely make tracking easier and more automated.

Thank you in advance.

Here is the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mKA3V4W2BSY8BcT8KBA6d8kgj0zOhnmqDWcjarAlBIY/edit?usp=sharing) of the sheet of the tracker I am trying to make. Feel free to edit it.

Thank you for those who will try..

Have a great day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have one option. It FLATTENS the range and returns the headers according on the MOD of the number of the MATCH of your status:

```
=BYROW(E3:E,LAMBDA(st,IF(st="","", IFERROR (INDEX(H8:I8,MOD(MATCH(st,FLATTEN(H9:I),0)-1,2)+1)))))
```

Adapt the ranges as needed

[image]